# How to check if transaction pays to my address?

Tags: transaction-data, viewkey

Let's assume I have an **address**, a **secret view key** for it, and a **transaction**. The transaction has been checked by a daemon to be valid.

How do I figure out if the transaction pays something (and how much) to the address? What are the operations I need to perform?

PS: I'm asking only about v11 and v12 protocol.

**Additional info:**

It's not obvious in the explanation below that some transactions have more than one pubkey. Specifically, it happens when the tx pays out to multiple subaddresses. A good explanation of what additional data should be processed is [in this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/how-to-parse-tx-extra-tag-additional-pubkeys-from-extra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the tx public key `R` from the tx extra field, and for each output, it's key 
`K` and index `i`, then using your private view key `a` and public spend key `B`, you own the output if:

`Hs(8aR||i)G+B == K`

To find out how much you received, take the encrypted amount `e` for that output index from the transaction's ecdhInfo field and decrypt:

`xor8(e, keccak("amount"||Hs(8aR||i))`

Note, `xor8` is XOR'ing the first parameter with the first 8 bytes of the second parameter, the result is the decrypted amount.

Comment: Thanks! Does 8 in 8aR stand for scalar multiplication?

Comment: It's a point multiplication. (ge_mul8).