# Where is the encrypted Monero amounts in a transaction?

Tags: transaction-data, confidential-transactions, amounts

Looking at a monero transaction, I can't see any amounts. Where is this encrypted exactly? Take for example: https://moneroblocks.info/tx/9adbcfa8fe9011c2451b9636d3b68312047e93ec4477bf894687fb182a93a4c2

I can see the fee was: 0.000161200000 XMR

But all the amounts are hidden. Where in the transaction data is this hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encrypted/masked amounts are stored in the tx `ecdhInfo` field.

If you want to view these masked amounts on an explorer:

- Visit: https://xmrchain.net/tx/9adbcfa8fe9011c2451b9636d3b68312047e93ec4477bf894687fb182a93a4c2/1
- Scroll to the bottom and click "Show JSON representation of tx".

If you want to view in a daemon:

```
print_tx 9adbcfa8fe9011c2451b9636d3b68312047e93ec4477bf894687fb182a93a4c2 +json
...
"ecdhInfo": [ {                                                                                              
    "amount": "5ba540ef53551f4b"                                                                                   }, {                                                                                                       
    "amount": "10779889c631fda5"                                                                             
  }],
```

Comment: its encrypted with the private view key and address? what is the function for such a thing if I wanted to decrypted it?

Comment: Decryption is covered in this answer: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11684/7493

Answer (score 1):

You will need the `address/subaddress` and `private view key` to decode the amounts.

Go to [xmrchain.net](https://xmrchain.net/search?value=9adbcfa8fe9011c2451b9636d3b68312047e93ec4477bf894687fb182a93a4c2) and fill in the missing address and viewkey.

Edit: Here's some light [reading](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/535.pdf) for deeper knowledge of Monero.
Transaction structure is described in detail in Appendix A/B.

Comment: i dont have any of that. i'm just viewing the blockchain as an outsider. i want to know where the amount is hidden in the Trasaction data that is given to us.